# Creating a new column into a dataframe based on conditions

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

For the dataframe df :

```
dummy_data1 = {'category': ['White', 'Black', 'Hispanic','White'],
           'Pop':['75','85','90','100'],'White_ratio':[0.6,0.4,0.7,0.35],'Black_ratio':[0.3,0.2,0.1,0.45], 'Hispanic_ratio':[0.1,0.4,0.2,0.20]    }
df = pd.DataFrame(dummy_data1, columns = ['category', 'Pop','White_ratio', 'Black_ratio', 'Hispanic_ratio'])
```

I want to add a new column to this data frame,'pop_n',  by first checking the category, and then multiplying the value in 'Pop' by the corresponding ratio value in the columns. For the first row,
the category is 'White' so it should multiply 75 with 0.60 and put 45 in pop_n column.
I thought about writing something like :

```
df['pop_n']= (df['Pop']*df['White_ratio']).where(df['category']=='W')
```

this works but just for one category.
I will appreciate any helps with this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`DataFrame.filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) and [`DataFrame.lookup`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.lookup.html):

First we use `filter` to get the columns with `ratio` in the name. Then split and keep the first word before the underscore only.

Finally we use `lookup` to match the `category` values to these columns.

```
# df['Pop'] = df['Pop'].astype(int)
df2 = df.filter(like='ratio').rename(columns=lambda x: x.split('_')[0])
df['pop_n'] = df2.lookup(df.index, df['category']) * df['Pop']
```

```
   category  Pop  White_ratio  Black_ratio  Hispanic_ratio  pop_n
0     White   75         0.60         0.30             0.1   45.0
1     Black   85         0.40         0.20             0.4   17.0
2  Hispanic   90         0.70         0.10             0.2   18.0
3     White  100         0.35         0.45             0.2   35.0
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Erfan, the data frame I am using has longer category names such as White,Black, Hispanic etc. I had put a simplified data frame here.  I'll appreciate it if you can mention which parts to edit in the code.

Comment: Can you edit your example data so it represents your problemcase.

Comment: I just did, apologies for the inconvenience!

Comment: It did! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Locate the columns that have underscores in their names:

```
to_rename = {x: x.split("_")[0] for x in df if "_" in x}
```

Find the matching factors:

```
stack = df.rename(columns=to_rename)\
          .set_index('category').stack()
factors = stack[map(lambda x: x[0]==x[1], stack.index)]\
          .reset_index(drop=True)
```

Multiply the original data by the factors:

```
df['pop_n'] = df['Pop'].astype(int) * factors

#   category  Pop  White_ratio  Black_ratio  Hispanic_ratio pop_n
#0     White   75         0.60         0.30             0.1    45
#1     Black   85         0.40         0.20             0.4    17
#2  Hispanic   90         0.70         0.10             0.2    18
#3     White  100         0.35         0.45             0.2    35
```